# Making sense of OOP in Lua

Tags: oop, lua

I do most of my programming in Python, and I use OOP practices for most of my projects. I recently started taking a look at the Love2D game library and engine. I managed to get some things configured, and then thought about making a GameObject class. But, what's this? Lua doesn't have classes! It has tables, and metatables, and other such things. I'm having a lot of trouble making heads or tails of this even after reading the documentation several times over.

Consider the following example:

```
catClass = {}
catClass.__index = catClass
catClass.type = "Cat"

function catClass.create(name)
    local obj = setmetatable({}, catClass)
    obj.name = name
    return obj
end

cat1 = catClass.create("Fluffy")
print(cat1.type)

cat2 = catClass.create("Meowth")

cat1.type = "Dog"

print(cat1.type)
print(cat2.type)
print(catClass.type)
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
Cat
Dog
Cat
Cat
```

What I do not understand is why changing cat1.type to "Dog" does not cause identical changes in cat2 and catClass. Does setting a metatable create a copy of the table? Google did not provide useful results (there are very few good Lua explanations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you index a table and a key does not exist then Lua will look to see if a metatable exists for the table. If one does then it will use the `__index` key of that metamethod to re-index your key.

When you created `cat1` it inherited the `catClass` metatable. Then when you indexed `type` it will see that `cat1` does not have a table entry called `type` and thus looks to the metatable to find it.

Then you set `type` on `cat1` to `Dog`, which only sets the table key of `cat1` itself, **not** the metatable. That is why when you index `cat1` again for `type` you get `Dog` and not `Cat`.

If you go to http://www.lua.org/ there is documentation and some older copies of the Programming in Lua, written by the authors of Lua itself.

Answer (score 4):

See the [`setmetatable`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setmetatable) documentation - the table returned is the table specified in the first argument.

This is a different table for each invocation of `create` (thanks to `{}`) and each new table is also distinct from the metatable used. No copy was made, but rather a *new* table was created which is then "linked"<sup>1</sup> to the metatable.

Thus there are three *different* tables in the above - `cat1` (with mt catClass), `cat2` (also with mt catClass) and `catClass` itself. Altering `cat1`, as done, therefor has no effect on the other two tables.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [Lua Metatables Tutorial](http://nova-fusion.com/2011/06/30/lua-metatables-tutorial/); the use of the `__index` presented in the metatable effectively emulates JavaScript's [prototype] resolution.

> *When you look up a table with a key*, regardless of what the key is, *and a value hasn't been assigned for that key* .. Lua will look for an `__index` key in the table's metatable .. *If `__index` contains a table, Lua will look up the key originally used in the table belonging to `__index`.*

However, `__index` has no affect on *assigning* a new index to one of the tables - the *particular* table is just modified as normal. (The tutorial also goes on to explain `__newindex`, if such write-through behavior is desired.)